# TextBox validation is not displaying errors

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

I've built a form for editing data in my WPF application.  I'm in the process of adding validation to the form.  I started by using [this article](http://wpftutorial.net/DataValidation.html) and [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com//en-us/library/ms753962.aspx), but the error template either shows all of the time or not at all.  I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here are the `ControlTemplate` and `Style` that I'm using.  They are in the form's Resources:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="TextBoxErrorTemplate">
    <StackPanel ClipToBounds="False" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Border BorderBrush="Red"
                BorderThickness="1"
                Margin="15,0,0,0">
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="adornedElement" />
        </Border>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Right"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Width="20"
               Height="20"
               Margin="0,-5,-5,0"
               Source="{StaticResource ErrorImage}"
               ToolTip="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ErrorConverter}, 
                                 ElementName=adornedElement, 
                                 Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)}" />
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Key="TextBoxErrorStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                    Value="Binding Converter={StaticResource ErrorConverter}, 
                                   RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, 
                                   Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And here's the `TextBox` that uses these parts:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="0"
            Margin="5,0"
            MaxLength="50"
            Name="NameBox"
            TabIndex="0"
            Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource TextBoxErrorTemplate}"
            Style="{StaticResource TextBoxErrorStyle}"
            TextAlignment="Left"
            TextChanged="NameBox_TextChanged"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource InvertedBoolToVisibility}, Path=AutoConfigureCameras, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type cs:EditLPRDetails}}}">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Mode="TwoWay" Path="Name" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <cs:RegexValidationRule Pattern="{StaticResource NamePattern}" />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Note that the validation logic in the `RegexValidationRule` class works.  When I put a valid string into the `TextBox`, it returns success, and when I put an invalid string into it, it returns failure.  Whatever is wrong, I believe the problem is in the `Style's Trigger`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem.

It turns out that my dialog box contains a `TabControl` and that is the cause of the issue.  I found the answer in [this article](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2008/02/19/wpf-validation-errors-disappear-inside-tabcontrol-when-switching-tabitems/).  Essentially, I need to put the contents of the `TabItem` that contains the controls being validated inside of an `AdornerDecorator` control, which is itself inside of a `Border` control.  Once that is done, then the error indicators all display properly.

I did not include the fact that my controls were inside of a `TabControl` at first because I didn't know that it mattered.  Live and learn.

Answer (score 2):

You are close, the `Setter` `Value` syntax for binding is not correct, plus you should set `Path` as `Validation.Errors`

```
 <Setter Property="ToolTip"
         Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ErrorConverter},
                         RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                         Path=(Validation.Errors)}"/>
```

Comment: I missed the opening left curly brace.  I just missed it entirely, didn't even see it.  Now the tool tip comes up and reads correctly, but the red border and the bitmap are still not displaying

Comment: then the problem is with the binding property.. Can you check if you have Name property properly defined in the DataContext of Textbox?

Comment: The DataContext is set at the `Window` level.  The `TextBox's` Text property is bound to the `Name` property of the `ViewModel` object.  The correct value displays in the `TextBox` when it displays an existing object, so that `Binding` is correct.  I've placed a breakpoint in the `IValueConverter` used in the `ToolTip Binding` and I've seen that breakpoint get hit.  I'm not sure which binding you're talking about.

Comment: yes i was talking about the same Name property... it is strange because i tried this and it is working fine..

Comment: I downloaded the sample code from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714593.aspx and that application works.  I can only assume that there's something in my code that's somehow preventing this from working.  I may have to use a different way to get the error image to display & the border color to change.

Comment: thats what i feel too.. because i created the similar programe as your code and it worked well

Comment: I pulled out Snoop and ran it against my dialog with the problem.  It looks like the `Validation.HasError` attached property is not being set to true.  It's grayed out & remains grayed out.  Yet the `Validation.Errors` collection does get an entry added to it.

Comment: I added some code to my code-behind and checked the values of the `Validation.HasError` attached property, which is true, and the value of the `Validation.ErrorTemplate` attached property, which is set to the `ControlTemplate` in my window's resources.  It seems that the `ControlTemplate` in the `Validation.ErrorTemplate` property is not displaying.